# How to prove that the smallest asymmetric tree has at least 7 vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

Find the smallest possible number of vertices an asymmetric tree can have (i.e. prove that no smaller tree can be asymmetric).
I think that the answer is 7, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that this tree should have at least two vertices.

Comment: You should be much more specific as to what you mean by 'tree', and for that matter by 'asymmetric' - it looks as though you mean just 'graph with no cycles' and 'no automorphisms' respectively, but e.g. many people use 'tree' to refer to rooted trees, either binary or of arbitrary degrees, and obviously the answer is much smaller there.

Answer (score 3):

If a tree has exactly two leaves, then it is a path, and so is not asymmetric. So any such tree has at least three leaves.

If any two of these leaves have a common neighbor, then we can switch those two leaves, and this gives a symmetry. Thus, the three leaves, call them $v_1,v_2,v_3$ have pairwise distinct neighbors $w_1,w_2,w_3$. In particular, the graph has at least six vertices. Suppose it had exactly six. Then $w_1,w_2,w_3$ cannot themselves be leaves, so they must connect to each other. There is up to isomorphism only one way to do this: $w_2$ connects to $w_1$ and $w_3$. But this graph has an automorphism: we can switch $w_3$ and $v_3$ with $w_1$ and $v_1$, respectively.

Thus, any graph with no automorphism must have at least seven vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a tree has at least 2 vertices, right?

You are right about $7$ and I believe the proof of this fact is a case by case verification!

There are in total $13$ trees with vertices ranging between 2 and 6 (1 with 2 vertices, 1 with 3, 2 with 4, 3 with 5 and 6 with 6 vertices).